# Issue with ANSI cursor movement in goroutine

Tags: go, terminal, command-line-interface, goroutine, cursor-position

### Background

I'm trying to write a Go library for creating terminal task-lists, inspired by the Node library [listr](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/listr).

My library, [golist](https://github.com/a-poor/golist), prints the task list out in a background goroutine and updates the text and status characters using ANSI escape sequences.

### The Problem

There's an issue where the final print of the list will *occasionally* have extra spaces included, leading to some spaces or repeated lines. Here are two examples – one correct, one not – both from runs of the **same exact code** ([here's a link to the code](https://github.com/a-poor/golist/blob/17b725823115505098aa62f322123eb3990747d1/examples/getting-started/main.go)).

### Example

Here's an example of what it should look like:

[image: golsit correct example]

([Here's a gist of the raw text output for the correct output](https://gist.github.com/a-poor/a817cb1a82db19fde888a6cd90124eee#file-golist-output-correct-txt))

And here's an example of what it sometimes looks like:

[image: golsit incorrect example]

([Here's a gist of the raw text output for the incorrect output](https://gist.github.com/a-poor/a817cb1a82db19fde888a6cd90124eee#file-golist-output-extraspaces-txt))

If you look at [lines 184 and 185 in the gist of the incorrect version](https://gist.github.com/a-poor/a817cb1a82db19fde888a6cd90124eee#file-golist-output-extraspaces-txt-L184-L185), there are two blank lines that aren't in the correct version.

Why is this happening and why is it only happening *sometimes*?

### Code

I'm printing the list to the terminal in the following loop:

```golang
go func() {
    defer donePrinting() // Tell the Stop function that we're done printing
    ts := l.getTaskStates()
    l.print(ts)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done(): // Check if the print loop should stop

            // Perform a final clear and an optional print depending on `ClearOnComplete`
            ts := l.getTaskStates()
            if l.ClearOnComplete {
                l.clear(ts)
                return
            }

            l.clearThenPrint(ts)
            return

        case s := <-l.printQ: // Check if there's a message to print
            fmt.Fprintln(l.Writer, s)

        default: // Otherwise, print the list
            ts := l.getTaskStates()
            l.clearThenPrint(ts)
            l.StatusIndicator.Next()
            time.Sleep(l.Delay)
        }
    }
}()
```

The list is formatted as a string and then printed. The following function formats the string:

```golang
// fmtPrint returns the formatted list of messages
// and statuses, using the supplied TaskStates
func (l *List) fmtPrint(ts []*TaskState) string {
    s := make([]string, 0)
    for _, t := range ts {
        s = append(s, l.formatMessage(t))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, "\n")
}
```

and the following function builds the ANSI escape string to clear the lines:

```golang
// fmtClear returns a string of ANSI escape characters
// to clear the `n` lines previously printed.
func (l *List) fmtClear(n int) string {
    s := "\033[1A" // Move up a line
    s += "\033[K"  // Clear the line
    s += "\r"      // Move back to the beginning of the line
    return strings.Repeat(s, n)
}
```

I'm using [this site](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) as a reference for the ANSI codes.

---

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have about why this is happening!

Let me know if there's any other information I can add that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ANSI codes are just a red herring. I pulled down the library and tried running it locally, and found that the following section is what is creating this issue:

```
 case s := <-l.printQ: // Check if there's a message to print
     fmt.Fprintln(l.Writer, s)
```

When the `printQ` channel is getting closed, this case is sometimes running, which seems to be moving the cursor down even though nothing is getting printed. This behaviour went away when I moved the call to close the channel after `l.printDone` is called.

```
...
// Wait for the print loop to finish                       
<-l.printDone                      
                                                                   
if l.printQ != nil {                     
    close(l.printQ)                                    
} 
...
```

This ensures that the loop is no longer running when the channel is closed, and thus the `s := <-l.printQ` case cannot run.